# iOS voiceover for vertical input type slider range incorrectly states swipe left right

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, voiceover

We have an ionic app that we're now trying to add Voiceover accesibility to.  Namely one widget is giving me trouble..

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="vertical" ng-model="myBoundValue" my-directive ng-class="{'closed':widget.state=='closed'}"/>
```

If I highlight over it, while the widget is closed.. the voiceover selector/highlighter, shows a massive `200x200px` box.. when it should instead be a vertical selector of `35x200px`.

I'm narrowing it down, and looks like the input button on the slider is getting highlighted, but when I go to click it (I added an `on-tap` event ... nothing happens.  I think I need to somehow get iOS voiceover to stop highlighting the button, or to notice the click on the button itself inside angularjs... any ideas here?

When voiceover speaks it states `100% adjustable` , `swipe left or right to adjust` ... but this is a vertical slider!?  Is this a bug in their accessibility related code?  Is there a work around to override that saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the CSS underneath my page was rotating the `<input` field, as well as the button/slider.

This was messing with the Voiceover logic, as it expects all sliders to be horizontal.  I ended up overriding it with it's own `aria-label` attribute.